# I don’t know the rendering logic of 'checked: {}' , but it does work, if delete it, the color will become lighter

Tags: material-ui

```
const GreenCheckbox = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: green[400],
    '&$checked': {
      color: green[600],
    },
  },
  checked: {},
})(props => <Checkbox color="default" {...props} />);
```

Detailed code please see [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/9ev7e).

Answer (score 0):

we call this selector and one of them is `checked` and that means that this radio button or check is checked and when its check we do what we want and in your position we make green color darker